# How to get text within <td> within <font> with bs4?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How should this parse with bs4 to get only country value?

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan=16>
            <font class=spy6><u>
                    <font class=spy1>Country</font> Brazil/BR<br>
                    <font class=spy1>Region </font> South America/SA <font class=spy1>TimeZone=America/Sao_Paulo
                    <font class=spy1>ORG/ASN</font> Brazil/BRORG/ASN<br></u></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

By this code i got all the text from the td, but I do not understand how to refer specifically to Country

```
 if resp.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    rows = soup.find_all('td')
    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
```

I got this string

```
 Country Brazil/BR South America/SA TimeZone=America/Sao_Paulo Location=-22.8305/-43.2192REG 
 Brazil/BRORG/ASN Locaweb Servicos de Internet S/A/27715
```

Comment: `row.find_all("font", {"class": "spy1"})` ? OR `find` instead of `find_all` to get only first element `row.find("font", {"class": "spy1"})`

Comment: The country name isn't within `<font>`, that just contains the label `Country`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the first `<font>` with `class='spy1'` within each td. The country is in the text node after that.

```
    rows = soup.find_all('td')
    for row in rows:
        country_label = row.find('font', _class='spy1')
        if country_label:
            print(country.next_sibling)
```